# maven-shade-plugin add application version to manifest

Tags: java, maven

I can't figure out how to get the maven-shade-plugin to include the application version from POM file into the Manifest file.
I found some examples for maven-jar-plugin which suggests including

```
<archive>                   
    <manifest>
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

within the plugis configuration section (http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/). I tried this for the maven-shade-plugin, but it doesn't work. I also tried to find some information if the org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer can do this but I could not find anything in the docs.

Has anybody an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just as described in [official instruction page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) about adding entries into manifest file, Version and Title of Implementation and specification could also be supported because they are entries of the manifest file.

However [Apache Maven Archiver](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/) is not supported in Maven Shade Plugin, so `<archive>` element is not work here. You have to use `ManifestResourceTransformer`, provided by Maven Shade Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>${project.build.mainClass}</Main-Class>
                            <Specification-Title>${project.artifactId}</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                            <Implementation-Title>${project.artifactId}</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This configuration is also used in my spring project, where I am able to directly retrieve version number via `Application.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` in java.

However simple replace to maven shade brings side effect for not including additional resource files as how `<archive>` plugin does in default, which would make projects that have properties resources not work such as spring projects. In most cases therefore, [maintaining dependencies by hand](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer) would be required along with maven shade, as the frequent usage example below:

```
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
        <manifestEntries>
            <Main-Class>${project.build.mainClass}</Main-Class>
            <Specification-Title>${project.artifactId}</Specification-Title>
            <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
            <Implementation-Title>${project.artifactId}</Implementation-Title>
            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
            <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
        </manifestEntries>
    </transformer>
</transformers>
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation about the all those entries? The only ones I see in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer) are `<Main-Class>`, `<X-Compile-Source-JDK>`, and `<X-Compile-Target-JDK>`.

Comment: To answer my own question, they aren't in the documentation because you can add anything you want.

Comment: @BradTurek You shouldn't add "anything you want" to a JAR manifest. Oracle has documentation as to what goes into a JAR manifest: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html

Comment: @Tobias, you're right—by "anything you want" I meant "any valid manifest entry in the form `<key>value</key>`"